# How to Configure Elasticsearch with hostgator Hosting in Magento 2.4.1

Tags: magento2, reindex, elasticsearch, magento2.4.1

I have installed magento 2.4.1 in my hostgator shared/Reseller hosting.All things are working fine but I am getting error Of Catalog/search Indexing required. But when I reindex from admin panel or from CLI i get the following error

> Catalog Search index exception: Could not ping search engine: No alive nodes found in your cluster

when i did research I found that hostgator does not support elasticsearch.
Any body know how to configure Elasticsearch in Hostgator and if not possible then how to solve this issue
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have got a similar hostgator shared/reseller hosting adn going to install magento 2.4.2.
To resolve your elastic search issue, you can create a separate ES a/c such as https://dashboard.searchly.com/ or https://cloud.elastic.co/ and in Magento Admin, add the ES setting in Catalog.

Comment: Hi Syce,
I also have a hostgator shared account and trying to install magento 2.4.2. while running commands such as bin/magento admin:user:create, it gives error and it seems php extension sodium is not installed. In shared account, we are not able to install and there is no root access. Are you able to perform these command and install php extensions such as sodium and opcache?